# How to query a limited number of rows from an Oracle database?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a large Oracle database with a large number of records that I need to process. I am validating the data within PHP and then generating XML code from the validated array of data. Due to the large number of results, the XML files become too large to be feasible to process. I am trying to break down the function to run 3 separate times and generate 3 separate XML files. I am trying to run the same query 3 times but each with a different WHILE statement at the end. I tried making use of the rownum method, but didnt realize that that you cannot do a `rownum > x and rownum <y` format. Anyone have any ideas? Here is a snippet of the code I tried running:

```
SELECT *
FROM useradmin.VSED_UNVALIDATED_VW tbl_vsed_unvalidated
WHERE (rownum < 10001)
```

and then another query with:

```
SELECT *
FROM useradmin.VSED_UNVALIDATED_VW tbl_vsed_unvalidated
WHERE ((rownum > 10000)
AND rownum < 20001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT *, rownum r FROM useradmin.VSED_UNVALIDATED_VW tbl_vsed_unvalidated)
WHERE r > 10001 AND r < 20001
```

You could build a little function to reuse:

```
function select_limit($table, $min, $max) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT *, rownum r FROM $table)
           WHERE r > $min AND r < $max";

   //return query result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
( select col1, col2, row_number() over (order by col1) r from tbl_vsed_unvalidated)
where r between 10000 and 20001
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for pagination. It can be done in oracle like that.

To understand it you should read about **rownum** pseudocolumn (In case you just don't want to read more data than is actually needed).

[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

```
select *
  from (select *
          from (select ua.*, rownum r
                  from useradmin ua)
         where rownum < MAX_VALUE)
 where r > MIN_VALUE
```